# JTabbedPane auto-resize

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jtabbedpane

I am developing a Java Swing application with Net-Beans. the application has a `JFrame` with tabbed panes. Now the problem is that when the frame is maximized, the tabbed pane only covers half the page and does not re-size to fit the new size of the frame.

Is there a way in Net-Beans to make the tabbed panes re-size with the enlargements of the `JFrame`, or does it have to be done programmatically.

If it has to be done programmatically, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sounds like a layout manager issue

Try setting the layout of the frame to `BorderLayout` before you add the `JTabbedPane`